# Flatmap() on Mono is being called twice (Java 11 and project reactor)

Tags: java, project-reactor

Here I am acting on a method called `accountDatafor()` which returns a `Mono<Response>`, the method I'm working in also returns a `Mono<Response>`.

The aim is to **avoid the `block()`** at the end of the pipeline to make this asynchronous as **the accountDataProvider is in another service.**

```
public Mono<Response> deleteAccount(String accountId) {
    return accountDataProvider.accountDataFor(accountId)
            .map(accountData -> {
                if (accountData.isActive) {
                    return deleteAccount(accountId);
                }
                return Mono.just(new Response());
            }).block();
}
```

However when I try using `flatmap()` here instead of `.map()` the deleteAccount() method is being called twice, which I can verify in the test.

```
public Mono<Response> deleteAccount(String accountId) {
    return accountDataProvider.accountDataFor(accountId)
            .flatMap(accountData -> {
                if (accountData.isActive) {
                    return deleteAccount(accountId);
                }
                return Mono.just(new Response());
            });
}
```

Inside deleteAccount()

```
var response = new Response();
accountRegistry.getSessions(List.of(accountId)).stream()
            .iterator()
            .forEachRemaining(session -> {
                    response.addToDeletedSessions(session);
            });
return Mono.just(response);
```

Failing line in test:

```
var res = sut.deleteAccount(accountId);
assertEquals(result.block().getDeletedSession.contains(accountId))
assertEquals(1, result.block().getDeletedSession.size())
verify(accountRegistry).getSessions(List.of(accountId));
```

Error:

> Wanted 1 time:

> But was 2 times:

Comment: You execute it twice. Each `result.block()` is a new execution, with all the steps

Answer (score 0):

First comment here, is you should use [stepverify](https://www.baeldung.com/reactive-streams-step-verifier-test-publisher) to validate the result

when you do that, it allow you to call just one time ( not twice as you are doing in this moments) because your error is here

```
assertEquals(result.block().getDeletedSession.contains(accountId))
assertEquals(1, result.block().getDeletedSession.size())
```

you are calling twice, for that reason, it is showing you that error